# Relational database structure for storing multiple hobbies of a user

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to register some users with basic details like username/email, password and their respective hobbies like reading, sports, dance etc and later on display users with similar hobbies. The current schema looks something like this.

```
Users

 - id 
 - email 
 - password 
 - country 
 - hobbies_id
```

```
hobbies

 - id 
 - user_id 
 - sports(values true/false) 
 - reading(values true/false)
 - dance(values true/false)
```

Each hobby is placed as a column in hobbies table.

What will be the most optimized schema if I increase the number of hobbies from 3 to 20?
Also, can someone help me with a query to select users with similar hobbies/hobby? For example, if John likes reading and sports, and Kim likes sports and dance then they have sports as a common hobby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `hobby_id` from users table. Similarly remove `user_id` from hobbies table. Hobbies is an entity in itself, and should store only information related to a hobby. Create a many-to-many mapping table between user and hobby

Comment: Creating multiple "similar" (hobby entity wise) columns is a SQL Antipattern. Ideally, hobby tabble should have two things (as per your current requirements): `hobby_id` and `hobby_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on comments by @Madhur Bhaiya, I would adress this with 3 tables:

```
users
 - id 
 - email 
 - password 
 - country 

hobbies
 - id
 - name (sports, reading, dance, ...)

user_hobbies
 - user_id
 - hobbie_id
```

The `users` table is the master table for users (one record per user).

The `hobbies` table is the master table for hobbies (one record per hobby). When new hobbies are created, you do not need to create new columns, just add new rows.

The `user_hobbies` table maps users to hobbies: it contains one record for each `user_id/hobbie_id` tuple.

Comment: This is obviously a good solution for this case but I'm facing a similar problem (for the sake of simplicity I'll stay with the question's schema). Now how would you design this so that a user can also create a new hobby. Then when selecting data, making sure that each user can see both the general hobbies and also the hobbies he have created?

Answer (score 2):

we can do with two solution ::

- @GMB's solution
- removed hobby table and save hobby data into user table only, in json data-type.

Comment: If we save it as json then won't it take bit long to fetch? And I already thought about storing in JSON, but I read in stackoverflow itself that it's not a good method.

Comment: nope, not take long time to fetch. what is mysql version? I am using mysql 8.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would recommend looking into [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This issue should be solved by implementing the Third Normal Form (TNF). For this, you should remove `hobby_id` from the `users` table and remove `user_id` from the `hobbies` table. A normalized example of one solution to this problem would be to create a new table that uses `user_id` and `hobby_id` as a Composite Key. See below:

```
users:
  - id
  - email
  - password
  - country

user_hobby:
  - user_id
  - hobby_id

hobbies:
  - id
  - description
  - type
```

In this situation, the `user_hobby` table would have a many to many relationship between `users` and `hobbies`. If a user has multiple hobbies, they will have multiple hobbies linked to their id in the `user_hobby` table, but each user and hobby should be listed only **once** in their respective tables.